LibGdx Android - PHP Sonderzeichenproblem in txt - Datei
I'm trying to save a high score name on my website via PHP.
User enters his name in the game. The name is written into the high score (offline in the game) via a text field (string) (everything still fits here). At the same time sent to the server (PHP), compared there with the other results (in a text file on the server) and written again into this text file on the server.
Everything works perfectly, only special characters (e.g. #,?,+) are saved incorrectly. The PHP code then only writes numbers into the text file instead of "#,?,+" (347) or something like that...
The problem is probably PHP. I don't know in which encoding (UTF8) or other, the username arrives in PHP.
In any case, according to the PHP program, only numbers are written to the file instead of special characters.

if (!name.equals("")) {
                Highscore.name = name;
                setActiveScreen(new Highscore());

                //Senden an Webseite
                String datasenden = "name11=" + name + "&punkte11=" + punkte;

                String URL = "https://www.test.de/zzz/mobile.php";
                Net.HttpRequest httpPOST = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
                httpPOST.setUrl(URL);
                httpPOST.setContent(datasenden/*"name1=Sepp8&punkte1=0"*/);

                Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpPOST, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                        Gdx.app.log("MSG", httpResponse.getResultAsString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(Throwable t) {
                        Gdx.app.log("LOGIN", "was NOT successful!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void cancelled() {
                        Gdx.app.log("LOGIN", "was cancelled!");
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors, images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

#?+ - all three of those have special meaning in the URL context. Sounds like you neglected to properly URL-encode the values you put into the query string of the URL that you are invoking your PHP script with.

How could I do that?

Don't know, so far you have only shown us the PHP code from the receiving end, but nothing about how you are making the request from the Android side.

Code - Android App...
